# Im making a on_member_join and remove event, but if the bot is in any other server and someone joins that server it sends it to my server they joined

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Sends a member joined msg in my channel when a person joins another server that has the bot in it. I also don't get any errors so everything works, just don't want it sending a msg to me when someone joined another server, that has my bot in it.

This is my code:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  channel = client.get_channel(870700792691167278) # replace id with the welcome channel's id
  await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has arrived!, check out announcments for server 
  and bot announcements!")
  await member.send(f"Thank you for joining Bot test, check out our annoucements channel for 
  server/bot updates!")
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  channel = client.get_channel(870700792691167278) # replace id with the welcome channel's id
  await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has left!, sad to see you go ")
  await member.send(f"Sad to see you leave duckmods :(")
```

is there a wait to get rid of it sending a member joined msg when they joined another server that had my bot in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`member.guild.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.guild).

Just add this to the beginning of your function.

```py
if member.guild.id != YOUR_SERVER_ID: return
```

This checks if the ID of the guild that the person joined is in your guild or not. If it is not equal, than return.

Your code should look like

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
  if member.guild.id != YOUR_SERVER_ID: return
  ... # Your code here
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
  if member.guild.id != YOUR_SERVER_ID: return
  ... # Your code here
```

Comment: UCYT5040 do you mind showing me where to put that? and how to use it, I'm new to this so any help is appreciated!

Comment: I specified to put this at the beginning of your function.